# How to access instance variables within string interpolations?

Tags: python

I would like to use string interpolation within instance methods: but am unsure how to access instance variables.

Here is the basic class declaration including the constructor:

```
class Validation:
    def __init__(self, name, type, count, script):
        self.name = name
        self.type = type
        self.count = count
        self.script = script
```

And here is where we want to access the list of variables. Note "globals()" is *not* correct..

```
    def __repr__(self):
        return "%(self.name)s: %(self.type)s that expects %(self.count)s Rows [%(self.script)s]" %self.__dict__
```

But that gives exception

```
(<type 'exceptions.KeyError'>, KeyError('self.name',), None)
```

So the question is: what should be used in place of %self.**dict** here?

Comment: You can omit the `self.`: `"%(name)s: %(type)s that expects %(count)s Rows [%(script)s]" % self.__dict__`.

Comment: what @alecxe said.  also `vars(self)` is a little nicer on the eyes than `self.__dict__`.

Comment: Why not just `return "%s: %s that expects %s Rows [%s]" % (self.name, self.type, self.count, self.script)`? It's as short as what you've already written and more refactor-friendly.

Comment: Avoid using `__dict__` directly. If one of those is a `property` instead of an instance attribute (or if the class uses `__slots__`), the variable won't be in `__dict__`.  This is also true of using `vars`, actually.  It really is best to just explicitly pass in the variables you want to use.

Comment: @alecxe  Pls make that an answer and I will accept it (with roippi's tweak as well)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should omit the `self.` and use [vars()](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#vars) instead of `__dict__` (thanks to @roippi):

```
class Validation:
    def __init__(self, name, type, count, script):
        self.name = name
        self.type = type
        self.count = count
        self.script = script

    def __repr__(self):
        return "%(name)s: %(type)s that expects %(count)s Rows [%(script)s]" % vars(self)


validation = Validation('name', 'type', 'count', 'script')
print validation
```

prints:

```
name: type that expects count Rows [script]
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all, [string interpolation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations) has been replaced by [string formatting](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string-formatting), so let's update that:

```
"{self.name}: {self.type} that expects {self.count} Rows [{self.script}]".format(**self.__dict__)
```

Second of all, since you're giving it the dict to work with, the keys in the dict are just the variable names, not `self.varname`.

```
"{name}: {type} that expects {count} Rows [{script}]".format(**self.__dict__)
```

Third of all, `__repr__` is intended to be valid-ish Python code to reproduce the object. Maybe you meant to put this as `__str__`? The `__repr__` should be

```
"Validation({name},{type},{count},{script})".format(**self.__dict__)
```

or honestly, since that's bad practice, just:

```
"Validation({},{},{},{})".format(self.name,self.type,self.count,self.script)
```

Let's try it:

```
#DEMO
class Validation(object):
    def __init__(self, name, type_, count, script):
        self.name = name
        self.type = type_
        self.count = count
        self.script = script
    def __repr__(self):
        return "Validation({},{},{},{})".format(self.name,self.type,self.count,self.script)
    def __str__(self):
        return "{}: {} that expects {} Rows [{}]".format(self.name,self.type,self.count,self.script)

>>> v = Validation('MyName','integer',26,lambda x: x)
>>> print(v) # or str(v)
MyName: integer that expects 26 Rows [<function <lambda> at 0x02D75468>]
>>> repr(v)
'Validation(MyName,integer,26,<function <lambda> at 0x02D75468>)'
```